# Let $G=\{x,y│x^4=y^4=e,xyxy^{-1}=e\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=\{x,y│x^4=y^4=e,xyxy^{-1}=e\}$

> 1.Show that $|G|\leq 16$.
>
> 2.Suppose that $|G|=16$
>
> > a.Find $Z(G)$.
> >
> > b.Find a familiar group that is isomorphic to $G/〈y^2 〉$ and show that these are isomorphic.

I am having trouble with part 2b. 
So far, I have 
Assume $|G|=16$
then $|G|/<y^2> = 8$ 
=> $|G|/<y^2> = |D_4|$

I'm not sure which direction to head in after this. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: There only two nonabelian groups of order $8$: the dihedral group $D_8$ and the quaternion group $Q_8$. See https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_8, which contains data that may help you differentiate between the two groups.